# Jquery selector with substr method

Tags: jquery, substr

I try to use the substr method with the Jquery selector:

```
<div style='position:static; bottom:0px; height:40px; background-color:#f00; padding:10px; width:715px;' class='downloadBar'>
<p class='nbDoc'>0 documents - 0 Ko</p><p><a href=''>Download</a></p>
</div>
```

Jquery part:

```
if ($('.downloadBar p.nbDoc').text().substr(0,1) == "0" )
$('.downloadBar p.nbDoc').text("No document selected");
```

So far this syntax is not working, is it possible to use it that way ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: try to log the value of `$('.downloadBar p.nbDoc').text()`

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/95Jef/2/

Comment: Have you put $(document).ready() around it?

Comment: You're sure there's no invisible characters or other white-space as the first character?

Comment: Note that your code is only useful for just one `.downloadBar` element, http://jsfiddle.net/6cne8/